# Using getCustomSchemas method to get custom fields for Google Directory User

Tags: google-api-java-client

Does anyone have experience using the user.getCustomSchemas() method to get custom fields from a Google Directory User?

I've created a custom attribute in Google and assigned values to several users:

- Category: `TestCategory`
- Custom fields: `TestField`
- `Visible to admin`
- `Single Value`

However, I always get a `null` value returned instead of the expected Map.

Can anyone provide an example of how to retrieve custom fields from a user object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So after playing with the Google API Explorer, I discovered that CustomSchemas are not returned unless you set the `projection` to "full". To do this using the Java library, simply add `.setProjection("full")` to the get user line.

e.g.

```
User user = dir.users().get(jdoe@domain.com).setProjection("full").execute();
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> customSchemas = user.getCustomSchemas();
System.out.println(customSchemas.get("Employee_Information").get("TestField").toString());
```